# Rails custom Coupon-System

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I creating a simple e-commerce for a friend and i want to implement a coupon system. I want coupons to be a new model and admin to be able to create a new coupon from admin panel like a simple scaffold.

My models are this for now.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
```

I know that i need an association Orders -> Belongs_to :coupon and Coupons -> has_many :orders or Orders -> has_one :coupon and Coupons -> belongs_to :orders. I want any order to have only one coupon.

But my main problem is how to create a form , to check if a coupon exists.

I know how to update the total_price etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure that the `name` or some other attribute of the coupon is unique in the `Coupon.rb` model. See the link below for more information.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Then you can index the Coupons by `Coupon.name`. This is will help two ways 1) if your admin attempts to create a coupon with a duplicate name or code they will get an error saying that coupon exits. 2) When a consumer enters a coupon you can simply check if it exits by calling `Coupon.find_by_name('NAME')` where `NAME` is what the consumer entered. If that returns nil then clearly they entered a coupon that was not created.

Comment: So, you suggest to add Coupon.find_by to my order controller. How to implement this on views?

Comment: If you have a form to create the coupon the backend will automatically check that the name is unique when the form gets submitted and show an error if the admin tries to create a duplicate. Are you still asking how to create the form on the front end? or the uniqueness validation on the front end?

Comment: No. My problem is not the validations to create the Coupon. I have stuck how to implement a form in the cart page to check if a coupon with the provided code exists and is valid and if exists add the amount to order or if not exists throw an error.

Comment: The best way to implement from a UX standpoint is to have a single input where they can enter in the promo code and then a submit button for that single input. Use AJAX to call a custom route and controller method to check if it's a valid code and then make any necessary changes on the backend. Then when then change the front end on a successful return from that AJAX function.